# Qt create Meego deb for nokia store

Tags: qt, meego, ovi

I have managed to compile a symbian executable for my device that I have uploaded to the nokia store. Now I want to know how I can create a deb to upload for the N9 and N900 but nothing in the documentation or anything else I can find helps. Please if know how I would appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find a very detailed description in MeeGo 1.2 Harmattan Developer Library about how to package your application before publishing in Nokia Store. Visit section [Packaging your application](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/guide/html/Developer_Library_Publishing_Packaging_your_application.html) which is the first topic of [Publishing](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/guide/html/Developer_Library_Publishing.html). (The second topic, [Meeting Ovi Store entry requirements](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/guide/html/Developer_Library_Publishing_Meeting_Ovi_Store_entry_requirements.html) might also be interesting for you.)